# Have I ruined my chances interviewing at the same company again?

Tags: interviewing, linkedin

Had an interview with a good company, went extremely well but I was not selected. I was told that I was a strong candidate and it was a very hard decision for them to reject me. The hiring manager also told me that he would like to interview me again if I reapplied.

After I found out that I was rejected, the HR of the company recommended that I get in touch with the hiring manager who is extremely senior. I dropped him an email asking for further feedback, telling him how I would like to connect on Linkedin, and keep in touch. He kindly replied and told me how he is open to connecting and keeping in touch. He then gave me further feedback.

I followed this up by acknowledging his feedback and how I wished I had introduced myself differently based on it, going into how I would have done it. Then asked him if in the near future he was planning to hire any new people for that role.

I have since heard nothing back (24hrs), he was initially quick with responding to me, and he has not accepted my Linkedin request during this time. So I am now worried I might have said something off in my last email which may ruin my chances of getting hired next time? I am likely to be interviwed by the same person again.

Is there a cause for concern. Or am I just threating over nothing?

Comment: I think you might be fretting over nothing. Could be the guy has Friday off, and isn't checking his emails.

Comment: Should I be concerned if he doesn't respond or connect over the coming weeks?

Comment: I see no reason to be concerned at all. If they guy doesn't respond ever again, he probably belongs to a company you wouldn't want to work for anyway.

Comment: "how I wished I had introduced myself differently based on it, going into how I would have done it." I don't get it, what is the point of doing that? That is a lot like saying, I now know the answer you were looking for, if I had known that before, I would have answered the question differently. In other words, it makes you sound desperate. Don't do that next time. As others have said, 24 hours is too short to wait, but you may just have blown the opportunity right there.

Comment: @MaskedMan Lesson learnt. If he does not reply or accept my linkedin in request then I think that says everything. A shame because I really did want to work in this company in the future. I told him that to build rapport.

Comment: @MaskedMan Good observation. Might be upgraded to a response. It is still not clear that the chance is blown, but a manager would start to worry that the candidate is oversensitive or not fully mature yet. The Golden Rule to be learned here: if an important conversation is going well, and offers the opportunity to be wrapped up, wrap it up. More words are more opportunity to make mistakes.

Comment: @bobo2000 24 hours is by far not enough time. People are very busy. Don't be nervous, and even if you are, don't show it.

Comment: Sigh , actually liked this company should have shut up instead of trying to build rapport. There is another job opening was thinking about applying, won't do it now.

Comment: Wait.....LinkedIn is still a thing?

Comment: @bobo2000 You seem to be desperately trying to talk yourself out of a job.  You went for an interview, but didn't get that job.  The recruiter said that you were welcome to apply for any future job that comes up.  There's no reason to keep hanging around him like a lost puppy - he will have other things to do now that the interview process has ended.  Just wait until they have another post that looks relevant and apply for it.

Comment: Just reapplied to another position in the company. I need to forget about it, and if I am reinterviewed by the same guy don't bring it up.

Comment: Thought I'd let everyone know that he accepted my LinkedIn request but hasn't responded to my email. Either way, I think I have nothing to worry about since he added me on his LinkedIn. Guess he must be too busy to respond my mail or forgot.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is there a cause for concern. Or am I just threating over nothing?

This might be an important connection for you but is very likely low on the to-do list of the person you are trying to connect with.

Give it more time. 24 hours isn't nearly enough.

And realistically if you ever apply for a job at this company again everything could be changed anyway. Your connection might no longer be there or the job may not be in this person's realm.

Stop worrying so much and continue on with your job search. There's nothing you could do about it now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. The reason they didnt answer is because you posed a question which cannot be answered.

Maybe the manager plans to hire, but it is not approved by HR -> They cannot tell you

Maybe the manager does not plan to hire -> They do not want to say 'no' to you

Maybe the company plans to hire in 6 month -> same

So do not worry if there is no reply. Next time you could have said instead: 'allright, can you keep me posted if something is coming up'.

And then without any problem (even if they do not plan to do that), the answer will be 'sure will do'.

Also if you see a job posted by the same company, just apply, but don't mention 'why didn't you inform me'.